Doxygen: How to add C comments in \code blocks?
In a Doxygen project, I am getting warnings like

warning: Reached end of file while still inside a (nested) comment. Nesting level 1

Presumably, this is due to C comments in \code blocks.  The overall document looks like
/** \page page_name Page Name
...
*/

that contain \code blocks like the following:
The compiler wraps the inline asm in \c \#APP / \c \#NOAPP annotations:
\code
func:
/* #APP */
    mov r22, r25
    mov r23, r24
/* #NOAPP */
    jmp callee
\endcode

which means the /** comment ends at the first */.
I have tried the solutions proposed in Doxygen escape nested comments in C but none of them works:

* / will display as such in HTML and not as the desired */.
&lowast; will be displayed verbatim, not as *.
In text like <tt>/* text *<!-- -->/</tt> HTML comment works, but that won't work in \code, either.

Using Doxygen v1.9.1
For all what I can tell, the generated HTML documentation looks fine despite the warning.

Please try commenting with //. Unlike popular belief, C supports the // syntax for a long time (since C99). More compatibility information here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99#Implementations

Doxygen 1.9.1 is from January 8, 2021, the current version is 1.10.0. With the limited information I'm not albel to reproduce the problem with the given version. Which settings are you using different from the default settings (i.e. what is the result of doxygen -x Doxyfile? please edit the result into the question). Also create a small example that shows the problem.

@vdavid: // is wrong, because that is not the code that GCC is generating, and // comments are not supported in assembly code.  Notice that code snippet is compiler generated assembly, not C/C++.

You can format the whole Doxygen block with C++ style single line // comments, using /// or //! to mark them as Doxygen blocks.

The Doxygen documentation block could be embedded in a block of lines beginning with the sequence /// or //!. The C compiler will treat those as C++ style // single line comments extending to the end of the line and will ignore everything in the comments including /* and */ sequences. This style of comments has been included in the C standard since C99.
//! \page page_name Page Name
//!
//! The compiler wraps the inline asm in \c \#APP / \c \#NOAPP annotations:
//! \code
//! func:
//! /* #APP */
//!     mov r22, r25
//!     mov r23, r24
//! /* #NOAPP */
//!     jmp callee
//! \endcode
//!

EDIT: The GCC compiler would generate a warning about a multi-line comment for the following code because of the backslash \ at the end of the comment:
//! \code
//! #define FOO \
//!      BAR
//! \endcode

Doxygen won't complain about it. The C compiler will splice the lines like this:
//! \code
//! #define FOO //!      BAR
//! \endcode

which will still compile OK.

This is one of the possible solutions, but as written in my comment with the original question, I could not reproduce the problem with the doxygen 1.9.1 version. The original question is not talking about the compiler, where the nested comment also may be a problem, but only about doxygen. Furthermore in the answer the used doxygen version is missing as well as the used settings.
